# gorm withCriteria and groping by domain class property

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0

I have the following entities in my app :

```
class Statistic {

    int hour
    ...
    Widget widget

}

 class Widget {
    String name
    ...
}
```

And I also have StatisticObj that is just DTO of Statistics domain

```
    class StatisticObj {
        int hour
        ...
        String widgetName
    }
```

I want to make criteria which would count Statistic and group by widgetName (so in the end I have count of Statistic per each widngetName) and then convert result to list of StatisticObj. My Criteria looks like this:

```
def results = Statistic.withCriteria {

    groupProperty('widget.name', 'widgetName')
   ..... projections { count ...} 
   }
    resultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(StatisticObj.class))
}
```

but in the end I get result which is not grouped.

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 .withCriteria {
        createAlias('widget', 'w')
        ...
        projections {

            groupProperty("w.name", "displayValue")
        }
      ....
     }
```

works now!

Answer (score 0):

For first groupProperty must be in projections. And it take only one property.

```
projections{
  groupProperty('widget.name')
  count
}
```

Try it I think it must resolve problem